# R studio can't use ggplot2 with no error message

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

I test the simple code like this:

```
g <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class))
g + geom_bar()
```

Then the R studio shows busy, and hang on until I shutdown the R studio program from the system. There is no error message. 
However, it can work in RGui.

I have already uninstall and reinstall the R and R studio. It doesn't work either.
Several days ago, I do the windows update, then it works for a while.

The version of OS is Win8.1 64bit. 
The versions for R and R studio are "R-3.3.1-win" and "RStudio-0.99.903"

Does anyone have any idea of this problem?

Comment: I'd suggest to take this to the RStudio support forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a bad interaction between 32bit versions of R 3.3.x and RStudio. You should be able to resolve this either by:

1. Downgrading back to R 3.2.5,
2. Switching to a 64bit version of R, or
3. Installing the [RStudio preview release](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/).